# Next Value for large dataset

Tags: r, data.table

I have data table

```
odo    LAT  
2.62    30.20
5.19    
7.61
18.82
19.06   40.10
19.35
20.54
20.81    70.90
```

I need to get the prev and next odo for each record.  i also need to get the next lat that is not blank.

final result would look like

```
odo    LAT      PreviousODO   NextODO  NextLat
2.62    30.20                  5.19    40.10
5.19              2.62         7.61    40.10
7.61              5.19         18.82   40.10
18.82             7.61         19.06   40.10
19.06   40.10     18.82        19.35   70.90
19.35             19.06        20.54   70.90    
20.54             19.35        20.81   70.90
20.81    70.90    20.54
```

I tried doing the following, which somewhat worked for PreviousODO, and NextOdo..didn't work at all for NextLat.  However, when i apply it to my larger data set of 33K records.  all of the previous and next odo starts to get random numbers. the previous and next odo should be based on the data being in order of the odo.  i tried ordering the data by odo and then doing the calculation, however i still don't get the right outcome.

```
atable<-data.table(odo = c(2.62, 5.19,7.61,18.82,19.06,19.35,20.54,20.81), LAT = c(30.2, NA,NA,NA,40.1,NA,NA,70.9))


atable[, PreviousOdo:=c(NA,odo[.I - 1]) ]
atable[, NextOdo:=c(NA,odo[.I + 2]) ]
atable[, NextLat:=c(NA,LAT[.I + 2]) ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that in two parts:

### calculate new odo

```
atable[, newOdo := shift(odo, -1)]
```

### calculate new lat with help of package `zoo`:

```
atable[!is.na(LAT), newLat := shift(zoo::na.locf(LAT), -1)]
atable[, newLat := zoo::na.locf(newLat)]
```

### Result:

```
atable
     odo  LAT newLat newOdo
1:  2.62 30.2   40.1   5.19
2:  5.19   NA   40.1   7.61
3:  7.61   NA   40.1  18.82
4: 18.82   NA   40.1  19.06
5: 19.06 40.1   70.9  19.35
6: 19.35   NA   70.9  20.54
7: 20.54   NA   70.9  20.81
8: 20.81 70.9   70.9     NA
```

Comment: @paveDave, thank you for the response.  i am getting an error:  'Error: n must be non-negative integer values (>= 0)  eval(expr, envir, enclos)
    eval(expr, envir, enclos)
    atable[, newOdo := shift(odo, -1)]
    `[.data.table`(atable, , newOdo := shift(odo, -1))
    eval(expr, envir, enclos)
    eval(expr, envir, enclos)
    shift(odo, -1)
    NULL'.

Comment: update `data.table` with `update.packages()`. Alternatively, use `shift(odo, 1, "lead")`

Comment: you can use `nafill` as well with version >= data.table_1.12.4

Comment: for the newLat part, it works great with a small dataset, however when i add the larger dataset the order of records changes so the incorrect lat picks up.  is there a a way to say order the records by odo to pick out the correct next lat?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't follow you with the "order of records changes so the incorrect lat picks up". Can you share the **smallest** reproducible dataset so I can check what's going on?

Comment: for example, the dataset is suppose to be in the order of odo.  so 2.62, 5.19, 7.61 is the first few records.  when i add the large dataset, the odo starts at 19.06, 270419.20,274572.11 (just at random).  since the records are not in any particular order, the next lat is given an out of sequence value.  let me see if i can reproduce with a dataset.

Comment: does `setkey(atable, "odo")` before running the code solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

In one step:

```
atable[, c("PreviousODO", "NextODO", "NextLat") := 
           .(shift(odo), shift(odo, -1), nafill(shift(LAT, -1), "nocb"))]

     odo  LAT newLat newOdo PreviousODO NextODO NextLat
1:  2.62 30.2   5.19   30.2          NA    5.19    40.1
2:  5.19   NA   7.61   30.2        2.62    7.61    40.1
3:  7.61   NA  18.82   30.2        5.19   18.82    40.1
4: 18.82   NA  19.06   30.2        7.61   19.06    40.1
5: 19.06 40.1  19.35   40.1       18.82   19.35    70.9
6: 19.35   NA  20.54   40.1       19.06   20.54    70.9
7: 20.54   NA  20.81   40.1       19.35   20.81    70.9
8: 20.81 70.9     NA   70.9       20.54      NA      NA
```

Comment: i'm getting errors with using shift.  i'm sure it's my version but i can't change it

Comment: I guess nafill() causes error too then because that's more recent?